# List won't add other ResultSet even it's already given

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm adding all the `ResultSet` in my `List <EmployeeModel`. I successfully retrieve all rows. But when it comes to adding all rows in `List` it only gets the first row and the loop already skip another row to be added. Any reasons why?

```
public void getStartEndTimeForOvertime(EmployeeModel employeeModel) 
{
    String query = "{call getStartEndTimeForOvertime(?,?)}";
    List <EmployeeModel> list = new ArrayList();

    try(Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(query);)
    {
        cs.setInt(1, EmployeeModel.getId());
        cs.setString(2, employeeModel.overtimeModel.getDay());

        try(ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery())
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                employeeModel.overtimeModel.setStartTime(rs.getString(1));
                employeeModel.overtimeModel.setEndTime(rs.getString(2));

                list.add(employeeModel);
            }
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error at getStartEndTimeForOvertime: "+ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("Error at getStartEndTimeForOvertime: "+ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Error at getStartEndTimeForOvertime: "+ex.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While iterating through the resultSet, everytime you are setting it on the same object of EmployeeModel
Instead do this

```
 while(rs.next()){
    EmployeeModel employeeModel = new EmployeeModel();
    employeeModel.overtimeModel.setStartTime(rs.getString(1));
    employeeModel.overtimeModel.setEndTime(rs.getString(2));

    list.add(employeeModel);
}
```

Comment: this is why you should learn to use `immutable` data value objects. these kind of stupid mistakes will never happen.

Comment: This still get only the first row even I created another object.